# Como acessar metodos de um array de objetos?

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade no qual tenho que desenvolver um sistema bancário, para isso tenho 3 tipos de conta(1 classe para cada tipo), portanto quero usar um array de objetos genérico. O problema esta em acessar os métodos dos objetos contidos no array, no qual o eclipse esta pedindo casting.

Classe principal:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class programa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Object[] arrayContas = new Object[50];
        Object elementoConta;


        System.out.println("1. Gerente. \n");
        System.out.println("2. Cliente. \n");
        System.out.println("3. Sair. \n");
        int opcao = input.nextInt();

        switch(opcao)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("1. Criar nova conta. \n");
                System.out.println("2. Vizualizar informações. \n");
                opcao = input.nextInt();

                switch(opcao)
                {
                case 1:
                    menuGerente.criarConta(arrayContas);
                    break;
                case 2:
                {
                    System.out.println("Digite o número da conta desejada: ");
                    int numeroDaConta = input.nextInt();
                    elementoConta = arrayContas[numeroDaConta];
                    elementoConta.print();
                }

                }

            }
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Classe de gerente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class menuGerente {

    public static Object criarConta(Object[] contas)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numeroConta = 0;
        String correntista;


        while(contas[numeroConta] != null)
        {
            numeroConta++;
        }


        System.out.println("Digite:\n 1 para conta simples.\n 2 para conta especial.\n 3 para conta poupança.\n");
        int opcao = input.nextInt();

        switch(opcao)
        {

            case 1:
            {
                System.out.printf("Digite o nome do correntsta: ");
                correntista = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println();

                conta novaConta = new conta(correntista, numeroConta);

                contas[numeroConta] = novaConta;
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                System.out.printf("Digite o nome do correntsta: ");
                correntista = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.printf("Digite o limite da conta: ");
                int limite = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println();

                contaEspecial novaConta = new contaEspecial(numeroConta, correntista, limite);

                contas[numeroConta] = novaConta;
                break;
            }

            case 3:
            {
                System.out.printf("Digite o nome do correntsta: ");
                correntista = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.printf("Digite o rendimento da conta: ");
                double rendimento = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println();

                contaEspecial novaConta = new contaEspecial(numeroConta, correntista, rendimento);

                contas[numeroConta] = novaConta;
                break;
            }   
        }
        input.close();
        return contas;
    }
}
```

Conta tipo 1:

```
public class conta {

    private int numeroConta;
    private String senha = "0000";
    private String nomeCorrentista;
    protected double saldo  = 0.0;
    protected String tipo = "Simples";


    //Construtor---------------------------------------------   
    public conta(String nomeCorrentista, int numeroConta)
    {
        this.numeroConta = numeroConta;
        this.nomeCorrentista = nomeCorrentista;
    }

    //Getters---------------------------------------------------
    int getConta()
    {
        return numeroConta;
    }

    String getCorrentista()
    {
        return nomeCorrentista;
    }

    double getSaldo()
    {
        return saldo;
    }

    //Métodos sacar, depositar e alterarSenha------------------------
    void sacar(double saque)
    {       
        if(Math.abs(saldo - saque) < 0)
        {
            saldo = saldo - saque;
            System.out.println("Saque realizado com sucesso!");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Saldo Insulficiente!");
        }
    }

    void depositar(double valor)
    {
        saldo = saldo + valor;
        System.out.println("Depósito realizado com sucesso!");

    }

    void alteraSenha(String senhaAntiga, String senhaNova)
    {
        if(senhaAntiga.equals(senha))
        {
            senha = senhaNova;
            System.out.println("Senha alterada com Sucesso!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Senha antiga incorreta!");
        }
    }

    //Print--------------------------------------------------------
    void print()
    {
        System.out.printf("O nome do correntista é %s. \n", getCorrentista());
        System.out.printf("O numero da conta é %d. \n", getConta());
        System.out.printf("A conta é do tipo %s. \n", tipo);
        System.out.printf("O saldo é de R$ %.2f. \n", getSaldo());
    }

}
```

Conta tipo 2:

```
public class contaEspecial extends conta{

    double limite;

    public contaEspecial(int numeroConta, String nomeCorrentista, double limite)
    {
        super(nomeCorrentista, numeroConta);
        tipo = "Especial";
        this.limite = limite;
    }

    void sacar(double saque)
    {       
        if(Math.abs(saldo - saque) < limite)
        {
            saldo = saldo - saque;
            System.out.println("Saque realizado com sucesso!");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Saldo Insulficiente!");
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        System.out.printf("O nome do correntista é %s. \n", getCorrentista());
        System.out.printf("O numero da conta é %d. \n", getConta());
        System.out.printf("A conta é do tipo %s. \n", tipo);
        System.out.printf("O saldo é de R$ %.2f. \n", getSaldo());
        System.out.printf("O limite é de %.2f. \n", limite);
    }

}
```

Tem mais coisas, mas já está muito grande kkkk.

Comment: "portanto quero usar um array de objetos genérico" - como assim ? Pode detalhar um pouco mais o que quer dizer com esta afirmação ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O compilador não permitirá você acessar um método de Conta por meio de um objeto do tipo Object, pois Object não contém os métodos de Conta.
Para fazer o compilador entender que existe um objeto do tipo Conta nesse array de Object, você precisa fazer casting, dessa maneira:

```
((Conta) arrayContas[0]).getSaldo();
```

Mas isso ficou meio feio, não ficou? Ao invés disso, você pode simplesmente declarar o seu array de contas como `Conta[] arrayContas = new Conta[50];`. Como `contaEspecial` estende Conta, você pode guardar ambos Conta e contaEspecial nesse array de Conta, dessa maneira seu compilador já saberá que os objetos desse array possui os métodos de Conta, então você poderá acessa-los simplesmente usando:

```
arrayContas[0].getSaldo();
```

Comment: Obrigado @user129564 de certo! Salvou!